# responseText is returning "Error" instead of the actual exception message returned from the server - jqgrid ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have created an application in ASP.NET MVC4 and hosted my application in IIS 7.5. I am noticing a wierd issue when I try perform an action in jqgrid which throws an exception from the server but it just displayed as "Error" in the jqgrid.

In the controller action, in the catch block, I am throwing a message which I want to display, which works just fine in my machine but when I try to connect to the server(my machine) from another machine using //machine-name/virtual-directory-name/, I am just getting "Error" displayed.

I am really suspicious that some setting in my virtual directory is causing this issue. Is there anything that I should change in the virtual directory settings to make this work.

I currently have

```
Anonymous Authentication - Enabled (Application Pool Identity)
ASP.NET Impersonation    - Enabled 
Windows Authenticaiton   - Enabled
```

Please help, thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Did you analyze the AJAX request in FireBug? What did you see? What was the exact response from the server?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: I tried to debug using Developer tools in IE and I was able to see that responseText has the message "Error" in the title tag instead of the actual exception message. So, I suppose the message is not returned from the server itself. Is there anything else you want me to check? Thanks for your initiative.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: This is the responseText I am receiving. 
"\r\n\r\n<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<meta name="\&quot;viewport\&quot;" content="\&quot;width=device-width\&quot;" />\r\n <title>Error</title>\r\n</head>\r\n <body>   \r\n<h2>\r\n Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.\r\n </h2> \r\n </body>\r\n</html>". Notice the title tag contains "Error", usually it contains the right exception message which I would parse and send to the jqgrid!

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: Do you have any clue why is this happening?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: I appreciate your time to understand my problem. I just found the solution, please take a look at it below. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling for a while, I figured out what the problem was and how to fix the issue. As I suspected, the problem is pertinent to web.config settings which can be resolved by adding an additional tag to the web.config file.

In web.config, add the following tag to the `<system.web>` tag.

```
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

There are three modes; On, Off and RemoteOnly. Setting it to Off will enable us to display ASP.NET specific detailed errors. RemoteOnly is recommended for security reasons in case by mistake you don't display application specific errors to remote clients.

Hope this helps someone so that they don't have to bang their head on their system.